# Combine two single-index dataframe in rows to one with multi-level index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe with single index. I want to combine them into one but with two-level index.

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
busjouney={'bus':['A','B'],'journey':[60,60]}  
daytable={'days':['Mon','Tue'],'journey':[60,60]}  
pd_busjouney=pd.DataFrame(busjouney)  
pd_daytable=pd.DataFrame(daytable)
```

I would like to combine these two data frames into one with two-level index like below:

```
days bus journey  
Mon  A   60  
     B   60  
Tue  A   60
     B   60
```

My cumbersome way is to create a dataframe with rows in Days and Columns in Bus and values as 60. Then use `pd.melt`and give index names. Anybody has better ideas?

Comment: table = {'days': ['Mon', 'Mon','Tue','Tue'], 'bus': ['A','B','A','B'], 'journey':[60,60,60,60]}

Isn't this what you really want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
df = pd_daytable.merge(pd_busjouney, how='left', on='journey')\
                .set_index(['days', 'bus'])

#           journey
# days bus         
# Mon  A         60
#      B         60
# Tue  A         60
#      B         60
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: pd_daytable.groupby('days').apply(lambda x: x.merge(pd_busjouney))\
                   .set_index(['days', 'bus'])

Out[1]: 
          journey
days bus         
Mon  A         60
     B         60
Tue  A         60
     B         60
```